# SSIS Lookup component failed to process the rows in the cache

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup, etl

I'm working with SQL Server 2008 R2 Integration Services. I have an etl process with a Lookup component, that was working just fine. I made some changes to data sources, but the amount of data is low in my opinion, 654 rows, it gives me the following error in the pre-execute phase:

> [Lookup AdLogin [2237]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80072023.
>   [Lookup AdLogin [2237]] Error: OLE DB error occurred while populating internal cache. Check SQLCommand and SqlCommandParam properties.
>   [Lookup AdLogin [2237]] Information: The component "Lookup AdLogin" (2237) failed to process the rows in the cache.  The processing time was 1.219 second(s).

I have memory available so I don't know what is happening, any help?

Comment: If you made a change to the datasource, does it still have the same data types? SSS does no implilcit conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code 0x80072023 indicates that the search scope of your LDAP query is too large and you are returning more than the allowed amount of results (1000 objects).

You can modify this setting in Active Directory, but the preferred practice is to limit your LDAP query to the values you're interested in. Perhaps your AD lookup only involves certain groups or people that you can filter on?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have duplicate keys in your look up table /SQL .This might be one of the reasons its not able to Cache the data properly.

Comment: I don't have duplicate keys, I only get two columns from my AD, one with logins and one with a personal id, logins are unique, other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My query to AD was more than 1000 rows, I was asking for all the users, active and inactive, it seams i was working until the amount of users pass 1000, I change my query to get only active users, I it works!

Thanks to Kyle Hale

Ana